# 1 Year old kitten doesn't like playing with 2 year old cat unless she is initiating it

Tags: cats, behavior, training, play, dominance

I've had her for over 6 months and my 1 year old kitten refuses to engage in play when my 2 year old male cat tries to chase and play. She always bugs me to play and is clearly more attached to me, but I can't play all day long and want them to be friends! She will occasionally initiate play with the 2 year old, but it's rare and only seems to be if she's in charge. When she first went into heat, my 2 year old male mounted her twice, but she has been fixed for months and he hasn't tried to mount since. I'd love to know how to get her to stop being a prima donna and acting like she's the queen, but my friend I got her from said her mom is very similar.

Is there anything I can do to nip this dominant attitude a bit and get her to play more with my other cat?

Answer (score 2):

First, I think it is helpful if you start thinking of it in terms of personality instead of attitude. Cats, much like humans, are who they are. There is no way of forcing her to become your ideal pet.

That said, there are things you can do to encourage them to play together. Try playing with your older cat while your younger cat observes from a safe distance. This way she can get to know his playful body language without feeling threatened.

As a next step, try to include your older cat whenever you play with your younger cat. It will take time, but slowly they should start to get more comfortable with each other.

Comfortable is a relative term here, of course. Not all cats get along and you might have to settle for them merely tolerating one another.